# Convert Date to String Like Twitter

Tags: android, string, date, twitter

i am creating app in which showing List of Tweets  i want to show time like Few Second ago,1m ago, 5m ago , 1h ago ... yesterday, and last on date

i am stuck with minute second few second

```
public static String getTimeString(Date fromdate) {

    long then;
    then = fromdate.getTime();
    Date date = new Date(then);

    StringBuffer dateStr = new StringBuffer();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int days = daysBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
    int minutes = hoursBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
    int hours = minutes / 60;
    if (days == 0) {

        int second = minuteBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
        if (minutes > 60) {

    } else

    if (hours > 24 && days <= 7) {
        dateStr.append(days).append("d");
    } else {
        dateStr.append(twtimeformat.format(date));
    }

    return dateStr.toString();
}

public static int minuteBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int hoursBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

getTimeDifference("your time", time);
```

here is class getTimeDifference

```
private void getTimeDifference(String pDate, TextView time) {
    int diffInDays = 0;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String formattedDate = format.format(c.getTime());

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {

        d1 = format.parse(formattedDate);
        d2 = format.parse(pDate);
        long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();

        diffInDays = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        if (diffInDays > 0) {
            if (diffInDays == 1) {
                time.setText(diffInDays + " day ago");
            } else {
                time.setText(diffInDays + " days ago");
            }
        } else {
            int diffHours = (int) (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));
            if (diffHours > 0) {
                if (diffHours == 1) {
                    time.setText(diffHours + " hr ago");
                } else {
                    time.setText(diffHours + " hrs ago");
                }
            } else {

                int diffMinutes = (int) ((diff / (60 * 1000) % 60));
                if (diffMinutes == 1) {
                    time.setText(diffMinutes + " min ago");
                } else {
                    time.setText(diffMinutes + " mins ago");
                }

            }
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // System.out.println("Err: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you help my anther same kind question ?? http://pastie.org/private/tjontopamvrngykrlv2dgg  see link

Comment: OK what you need there?

Answer (score 0):

Date to String conversion is very easy. please see below 3 lines code.

```
 // Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat used for formatting 
 // the string representation of date (month/day/year)
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

 // Get the date today using Calendar object.
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
 // Using DateFormat format method we can create a string 
 // representation of a date with the defined format.
String reportDate = df.format(today);

// Print what date is today!
 System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);
```

If you want to pass your own date Object then pass it in below code.

```
String reportDate = df.format(yourDateObject);

// Print what date is today!
 System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);
```

Thanks for your positive response.

Comment: thank you but its not my answer i want just like twitter hope you understand  my question

Answer (score 0):

see this solution

```
public static String getTWTimeString(Date fromdate) {

long then;
then = fromdate.getTime();
Date date = new Date(then);

StringBuffer dateStr = new StringBuffer();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

int days = daysBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
int minutes = hoursBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
int hours = minutes / 60;
if (days == 0) {

    int second = minuteBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
    if (minutes > 60) {

        // dateStr.append(hours).append(hours > 1 ? "h" : "h");

        if (hours >= 1 && hours <= 24) {
            dateStr.append(hours).append("h");
        }

    } else {

        if (second <= 10) {
            dateStr.append("Now");
        } else if (second > 10 && second <= 30) {
            dateStr.append("few seconds ago");
        } else if (second > 30 && second <= 60) {
            dateStr.append(second).append("s");
        } else if (second >= 60 && minutes <= 60) {
            dateStr.append(minutes).append("m");
        }
    }
} else

if (hours > 24 && days <= 7) {
    dateStr.append(days).append("d");
} else {
    dateStr.append(twtimeformat.format(date));
}

return dateStr.toString();
}

public static int minuteBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int hoursBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
  return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
  return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
 }
```